# Will this replacement induction cooktop fit in the cutout for the old cooktop?

Tags: kitchen-counters, measuring

My [induction cooktop](http://www.baumatic.com.au/slimline/cooktops/induction/bhi650-60cm-slide-control-induction-cooktop.html) died recently, and needs replacing. As it is under warrenty, and there are no replacements currently available, we have been offered store credit at the place we bought it from. While we're at it, we are looking to get a slightly [different model](http://www.electrolux.com.au/Products/Cooking/Cooktops/Induction/EHI645BA).

The question is, will the newer model fit into the existing cutout of our granite benchtop, or will we need to stick with the same model we have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original

According to the documentation the original requires a 495mm x 565mm cutout, and has an overall size of 520mm x 590mm.

> [image: Dimensional Drawing]
> <sup>[Source](http://www.baumatic.com.au/slimline/cooktops/induction/bhi650-60cm-slide-control-induction-cooktop.html)</sup>

## New

According to the documentation the new unit requires a 490mm x 560mm cutout, and has an overall size of 520mm x 590mm.

> [image: Listed Specifications]
> [image: Dimensional Drawing]
> <sup>[Source](http://www.electrolux.com.au/Products/Cooking/Cooktops/Induction/EHI645BA)</sup>
> <sup>[Source (PDF)](https://product.electrolux.com.au/Public/File/19938)</sup>

## Side by Side

```
                Old     New
Width           590     590
Depth           520     520
Cutout Width    565     560
Cutout Depth    495     490
```

## Verdict

While the new model requires a bit smaller cutout, the overall size of the cooktops are the same. So other than possibly requiring a bit of shimming, the new model should fit without a problem.

Comment: What would require shimming?

Comment: @HerrBag It appears the unit has built in spacers. If it didn't, the smaller square peg would slide around in the larger square hole.

Answer (score 0):

The new unit specifies the cutout (aperture) as 5 mm smaller (in both width and depth) than your original.  I doubt its a problem.  What does your vendor say?

Comment: I'll be speaking to the vendor on the weekend when we go in. I thought the same, but wanted to see if anyone had any other thoughts.